# What is the name of the Cygwin package manager?

Tags: cygwin, package-management

I'm not a regular Cygwin user. I installed Cygwin and Cygwin64 for testing proposed patches. I tried to perform a `git clone`, but it failed with `-bash: git: command not found`. So I need to install Git, which should be a relatively simple operation.

Cygwin does not appear to supply documentation related to packages and their management:

```
$ man -k package
package: nothing appropriate.
```

In the terminal, I tried `install git` and `cygwin install git`. The former failed with `install: missing destination file operand after ‘git’`. The latter failed with `-bash: cygwin: command not found`. (For completeness, I also tried `apt-get` (Ubuntu), `yum` (Red Hat/Fedora), and `pkg_add` (BSDs) with the same results. I even tried just `pkg` and `package` with the same result).

What is the name of the Cygwin package manager?

Comment: [sad face](http://superuser.com/questions/41093/installing-cygwin-packages-from-the-command-line?rq=1)

Comment: @jww Is Cygwin even considered a linux distribution though? ;)

Comment: @jww - Cygwin isn't a Unix nor Linux shell.  Its just a collection of tools....

Comment: @Ramhound - forgive my ignorance. Are you claiming Cygwin is not providing the shell I am using (that icon they place on the desktop called *Cygwin Terminal*)?

Comment: @jww - I will bite.  I actually am saying that Cgywin isn't a Unix or Linux shell. it is a Windows application which supports ported GNU tools, which runs in a shell with similar commands, Cygwin specifically is a terminal application for that capability and those tools.  The Cygwin website itself describes Cgywin as the following **"Cygwin is a distribution of popular GNU and other Open Source tools running on Microsoft Windows. The core part is the Cygwin library which provides the POSIX system calls and environment these programs expect."** [Proof](http://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.what.what).

Comment: The linked question isn't a duplicate. It answers a different question than that being asked in this question. The name of the Cygwin package manager is [setup.exe](https://cygwin.com/install.html). It's the same file you used to install Cygwin. It's used to install, remove, and downgrade packages. It can also be used to install the source for any packages. [There isn't much documentation for it](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages) because Cygwin's package management is pretty simple and bare-bones.

Comment: @Starfish - Thanks. The question's handling is due to a fellow named Ramhound. He and I have had problem for a couple of years now. Just about anytime I ask a question, he follows me casting down votes and providing argumentative comments. I've observed his behavior with others, and its probably best to avoid him with comments like *"The linked question isn't a duplicate..."*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default package manager, but there should be either [an `apt-cyg` or a `cyg-apt`](https://superuser.com/questions/40545/upgrading-and-installing-packages-through-the-cygwin-command-line) available to you as packaged by the installer.

Comment: It looks like its `apt-cyg`, but its broken for me. I can't get it to install anything due to MD5 checksum issues. Shrug... Others have the same problem: [md5sum failure results in packages not being installed](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/issues/37).

Comment: That's not correct. [setup.exe](https://cygwin.com/install.html) is the default package manager.