# Is there an equivalent of apt-get in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [upgrading and installing packages through the cygwin command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/40545/upgrading-and-installing-packages-through-the-cygwin-command-line)

Is there an equivalent of apt-get in Cygwin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be [alternatives for apt-get in cygwin](http://bluwiki.com/go/CygwinTips#Where_is_apt-get_for_cygwin), but I can't say anything about them.

Comment: Can't get any of them to work.

Comment: @Zubair: I'm sorry, I can't help you on that, because I never used one of them.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I guess using cygwin is a poor man's Unix anyway, so maybe better off using VirtualBox

Answer (score 5):

There is an [apt-cyg](http://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/) script.

Check out the issues tab.  There are some known issues although they appear to be clearing up.  It also requires that you install subversion to maintain the latest copy.

Comment: I tried apt-cyg. It just says "command not found"

Comment: Did you follow the link?  Look at the GettingStarted link - http://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/wiki/GettingStarted