# How to install new packages on Cygwin?

Tags: updates, cygwin, installation

I installed the latest version of **Cygwin** with a number of packages.
I soon realised that I need more packages (such as `wget`, etc) and I couldn't find a way to install the new packages without running the set up again and reinstall everything from scratch.

What I'm looking for is the equivalent of apt-get on Cygwin (if such a thing exists).

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/40545/upgrading-and-installing-packages-through-the-cygwin-command-line/301026#301026

Comment: see answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745275/can-i-script-a-cygwin-install-to-include-certain-packages

Answer (score 162, accepted):

There is no package management in Cygwin outside of the setup program. The setup only applies updates to your current installation, it does not overwrite packages that what you already have (unless you have explicitly said so).

So rerun the setup program to install new packages.

Comment: let's say I have a list of the following packages `cygwin-devel gcc-core git libcom_err-devel libcom_err2 libcrypt-devel libcrypt0 libedit-devel libedit0 libgcc1 libgssapi_krb5_2 libiconv-devel libiconv2 libintl-devel libintl8 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-devel libkrb5_3 libkrb5support0 libncurses-devel libncursesw10 libopenssl100 libssp0-4.9.2-3 make openssl-devel w32api-headers w32api-includes zlib-devel zlib0-1.2.8-3 git wget` How might i install them?

Comment: Someone already answered this [here](http://superuser.com/questions/40545/upgrading-and-installing-packages-through-the-cygwin-command-line/301026#301026). Asking me directly was the wrong way to get a timely answer. :)

Comment: Does the setup.exe version have to be the same exact version as was initially installed?

Comment: No, that's the whole point. You will get the option to upgrade what you want if you run a more recent version of setup than what you already had installed.

Comment: see answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745275/can-i-script-a-cygwin-install-to-include-certain-packages

Answer (score 96):

There is a package called [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg) that may be what you are looking for. It appears to be based upon apt-get.

> apt-cyg is a command-line installer
>   for Cygwin which cooperates with
>   Cygwin Setup and uses the same
>   repository. The syntax is similar to
>   apt-get.

An example command would be

```
$ apt-cyg install yourPackage
```

To install it you need wget, tar, gawk, and bzip2. You can download all these packages from the Cygwin [packages list](http://www.cygwin.com/packages/).

Comment: how do you install apt-cyg once you have downloaded wget, tar, gawk, and bzip2? thx

Comment: answering my own question: http://superuser.com/a/41139/280964

Comment: apt-cyg seems as a great options but I had many troubles (permissions, hard links, etc) and I got back to old approach - using the installer. apt-get != apt-cyg

Answer (score 28):

I find [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) very useful for windows installations management (new, upgrade and removal), and **cygwin** is no exception!

I installed **cygwin** using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), and since Chocolatey is installing using quiet/silent mode, you are not asked to select any packages and **cygwin** is installed with bare minimum packages :-(.

However, every time you wish to install a new package it is really-really, easy just use: 
`--source=cygwin`.
For example, installing bash:

> choco install bash --source=cygwin

Comment: I have had a very good experience with choco. I recommend it and wish it would be higher in google search results.

Answer (score 22):

Re-run the setup program again.  This is how you update Cygwin as well.

Comment: thx, for those in doubt: it does not reinstall everything, it simply install the new packages that you select

Comment: I am doing this right now to install a single package, `unzip`. All I did is opened the setup GUI, searched for unzip, checked it to install bin. However, it almost looks like it's reinstalling everything. I see it going through packages like grep, libgtk, etc. It's been running for about 10 minutes and is only about 50% done. Is that normal? FYI, this is probably the first time in 8+ months I've run setup, so maybe all my packages are out of date?

Comment: @SSilk it updated the old packages. Thats normal.

Answer (score 7):

You need to install 'lynx' at first in a common way.
Then open cygwin and write this:

1. `lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg`
2. `install apt-cyg /bin`

Now you can use package manager `apt-cyg install`

For more information see https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck with the same issue while trying to use curl on Windows and just got it resolved. Posting it here, now cause it might help someone.

The best way is to just use cygwin's setup.exe and select additional packages that you need. Go here: http://www.cygwin.com/install.html

> "When installing packages for the first time, setup*.exe does not
>   install every package. Only the minimal base packages from the Cygwin
>   distribution are installed by default. Clicking on categories and
>   packages in the setup*.exe package installation screen will provide
>   you with the ability to control what is installed or updated."

Answer (score 3):

Hi I know that it's old topic but just to add some info:
You can also install program called MSYS2 which has the package manager PACMAN from Arch Linux and You are able to install all packs avaible for Arch :)
Just `pacman -S packageName` and hit enter and it will dl it for You:)

Cheers :D

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is using Cygwin. You cannot mix and match bits of Cygwin with bits of Msys2

Comment: HI i know  but check post above abouts Babuka which is looking like some project based on Cygwin like MSYS2 I've been talking about.

Comment: There is a difference between Babuka which **includes** Cygwin and MSYS2 which is **based** on Cygwin.

Comment: ah ok then sorry for misleading my bad :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Babun](https://babun.github.io/) which is built around Cygwin and includes the package manager `pact`.

Babun supports installing new packages out of the box:

```
pact install wget
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users, Use the Installation Setup, You can get the setup here https://www.cygwin.com/
It will guide you through the relevant steps until you reac the package window.
Make sure you select Full in the **View drop down** . Then select the packages you want to add and install
[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSD6J.png)