# Chocolatey install of Cygwin keeps looping through sites?

Tags: windows-7, installation, cygwin, uninstall, chocolatey

So I have been trying to install Cygwin via chocolatey here, using:

```
cinst Cygwin
```

However, I get this screen
[image]
which just goes through different sites, and keeps 'failing'.

Now I am concerned... what do I do here? If I abort... how do I remove the gunk it has installed? Should I care? But more importantly, what/how do I remedy this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be quite a lot of errors there. The main thing I can see is that appears to be failing to connect to any of the Cygwin repositories (so called "mirrors", these keep copies of the software). You might try, from a command prompt (not BASH ;) to `ftp mirrors.kernel.org`. You should get back a couple of lines saying that you've connected and a welcome. That will tell us whether you have a network issue of some kind

Comment: @JulianKnight Right, so if I do that, then after a long pause, the regular "C:\>" is not replaced by an "ftp>"...

Comment: You might not get a prompt back, when I did it in PowerShell it doesn't return a prompt but if you get the 2 messages, you have successfully connected.

Answer (score 2):

The use of BASH is inconsistent with Chocolatey commands. I would recommend cmd.exe or powershell.

With Cygwin install, it could be a variety of factors causing this issue. Do you have a link to that image or the text somewhere so we can take a look at what might be happening? It's hard to make out from the image.

Comment: Hmm, sorry but I thought BASH is the cmd.exe .... I guess I dont understand. :-/

Comment: When you start up the shell, what do you use? BASH is not the same as cmd.exe is not the same as powershell.exe.

Comment: So, I can start with either cmd.exe, gitBash, or PowerPC. (I am using comEmu).

Comment: Good man. ConEmu is awesome. :)