# CYGWIN PACKAGE FINDER

Tags: terminal, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [upgrading and installing packages through the cygwin command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/40545/upgrading-and-installing-packages-through-the-cygwin-command-line)

I am new with Cygwin terminal. I am currently experiencing missing / unincluded packages such as the sudo command, svn command and other basic packages. My problem goes like this:
how can I install the missing packages I am aiming? In what way will I determine if what package is the command I am looking for is included?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) only installs a partial subset of all available packages.  To find the package that installs the command you want, execute:

```
cygcheck -p COMMAND
```

where `COMMAND` can be any word or a regular expression that is matched against the description of every package.  This requires Internet access to work.

Once you know which new packages you want to install, simply run the install again (i.e., pretend you are installing for the first time), and when the installer displays the "Select Packages" screen, click on `View` once to switch to `Full` view.  This lists every available package in alphabetical order, showing which are installed and which aren't. The ones that are *not* installed have the word `Skip` next to them.  Scroll through the list, and click on `Skip` next to a package name to select that package to be installed — the `Skip` will change to a version number to indicate the package has been selected for install.  When you have selected everything you want, click `Next` to continue the install.

You can do this anytime and you should to get updates to packages.  The updates are automatically selected if they are available.

Comment: Also, you can search for packages at http://cygwin.com/packages/.